# Laravel blank white page with data load from JSON file

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to make sure my data is loading correctly into my laravel app. When I navigate to localhost/data it appears to be grabbing the data because it takes a while to load, but then just displays a blank white page. I'm wondering if my JSON file is too large for it to handle?

My SiteController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class SiteController {
  public function index() {
    $results = file_get_contents("http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json");
    $data = json_decode($results, true);
    dd($data);
    }
}
  ?>
```

My routes:
<?php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\SiteController;

Route::get('/data', [SiteController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And here's the link to the JSON file I'm accessing. http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json

Thank you!!

Comment: The whole json file is 19.2 MB, so  you might be running into memory issues. A blank white page is often a 500 Internal Server Error, so you can check the Laravel logs in `/storage/logs` and the error logs for your web server to see if there's any information there.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the log. I have the JSON file saved in my project as well-would it be easier to access it locally? I tried $results = file_get_contents('/storage/geisingerDB.json'); which is where it's stored but it gave the error "file stream not found"

Comment: When you add a slash to the beginning of the path, it starts looking from the system root, not the project root. You can use `storage_path('geisingerDB.json')` instead. But if it's a memory issue, loading it locally may or may not help.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Would using a SQL database be a better approach?

Comment: Yes. If you can load that json into a database, it would be must faster and less memory intensive

Comment: One more question, Is the data there, just not able to display? Can I build out a search function in laravel to access that data or will that not work?

Comment: Since it's giving the white screen, it's hard to tell where it's breaking. There's data in the file, so if you can get it into the database, you'll be able to search it easier.